# Deletion of the tag [flashforge-adventure-3]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [`flashforge-adventure-3`](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/flashforge-adventure-3/info) was created due to a mis-spelled tag in a question which has since been corrected. Can this tag be deleted?

(bad) Alternatively, can it be added as a synonym for the [`flashforge-adventurer-3`](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/flashforge-adventurer-3/info) (the correct tag has an extra `r`)

Lastly, As I (thankfully) don't have access to the mod tools, can someone with access do the needful?

Comment: Yeah, rename it

Answer (score 2):

Spelling error, so rename is fine. Synonym is not necessary, tag may be deleted IMHO.